# sql query by passing te values in one table

Tags: sql

can any one help me in generating query for the below scenario?

i have twop tables TableA and TableB

TableA has  teh follwing columns EMPLOYEEID, SKILLSETCODE,CERTID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLEINITIAL

TableB has two columns EMPLOYEEID  and key_user

i want to SELECT EMPLOYEEID, SKILLSETCODE,CERTID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLEINITIAL FROM TableA WHERE EMPLOYEEID = (select employeeid from TableB  where key_user='249')

how can i generate a sql query for the above scenario?

Comment: make you question more clear, you want to develop this in jquery?? you want to know to call database query from jquery?? as sql statement? if yes u already did it , give more details

Comment: did you try the statement you wrote here?

Comment: if the answer was helpful, feel free to up-vote it - would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join.

```
SELECT TableA.EMPLOYEEID, SKILLSETCODE,CERTID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLEINITIAL 
FROM TableA, TableB
WHERE TableA.EMPLOYEEID = TableB.employeeid 
and TableB.key_user='249'
```

Comment: If the DBMS supports it, a natural join would be neater (`... FROM TableA NATURAL JOIN TableB WHERE key_user = '249'`)

Comment: @Chris - true, though I tend to do a lot of Sybase stuff so I kind of weigh towards the most portable SQL in my preferences

Answer (score 0):

Alternately

```
SELECT TableA.EMPLOYEEID, SKILLSETCODE,CERTID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLEINITIAL 
FROM TableA
  INNER JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.EMPLOYEEID = TableB.employeeid 
WHERE TableB.key_user='249'
```